# Нужна помощь с Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony2

Я новичек в Symfony. Нашел проект какого то программиста и пытаюсь в нем разобраться. И сразу тупик: при заходе на главную меня перебрасывает на ***/login***. Где мне найти эту переадресацию, что бы убрать? Спасибо

Comment: Возможно стоит начать разбор чужого кода с файла app/config/routing.yml

Comment: разбирался с этим файлом, но разве роутинг может делать переадресацию?

Comment: нет, но там указан контроллер в котором возможно стоит переадресация, а также в конфиге можно указать маршруты для которых требуется авторизация. И еще не плохо было бы убедится что в .htaccess нет переадресации, если сайт работает на Apache сервере

Comment: в htaccess нету ничего, а в каком конкретно конфиге смотреть?

Comment: вот что нашел: если удалить это 

    fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
перестает работать сайт. Но беда в том, что я не могу найти файл ***all.xml***

Comment: возможно это поможет https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app/config/security.yml

Возможно тут стоит защита урла типа:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

А тут пароли и логины:

```
providers:
```

Answer (score 1):

- Нужно посмотреть сколько "бандлов" (Bundle) в папке `/src`.
- Каждый такой пакет `Bundle` заканчивается на слово Bundle.
- В бандлах есть контроллер (то что вам нужно), к примеру если у вас /src/TestBundle/Controller то нужно смотреть файл (DefaultController.php) который в папке Controller и заканчивается на слово `...Controller.php`, где находится файл контроллера, который обрабытывает запрос.
- Вам нужно посмотреть все контроллеры во всех бандлах и посмотреть "роуты"
  `Routes`.

над функцией которая обрабатывает ваш запрос должно быть написано что то похожее (к примеру):

```
 /**
 * @Route("/")
 */
public function index_catch() {
    ///////// ......
    return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
}
```

`return $this->redirectToRoute('login');` это редирект, который может быть реализован по [разному](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#redirecting).
Код со звездочками это в `symfony` називается [annotation method route](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html)

Здесь в примере я показал как может быть реализован редирект в симфони. В более старых версиях синтаксис может отличатся, но в любом случае нужно смотреть файлы контроллеров. В вашем случае нужно просмотреть все бандлы и все контроллеры (в лучшем случае у вас будет один бандл в папке `/src` и один файл контроллера в нем, но может быть много бандлов в папке `/src` контроллеры которых нужно просмотреть). Верхний код должен быть в одном файле со следуйщим кодом (там где `Route` могут быть и другие параметры):

```
   /**
     * @Route("/login",name='login')
     */
    public function index_catch() {
        ///////// ......
        return $this->render('Bundle:Default:login.twig');
    }
```

Comment: просмотрел все контроллеры - ничего не нашел

Comment: тогда может быть файл `.htaccess` нужно смотреть. Или попробуй набрать Ctrl + F в своей IDE и поискать `header('Location:`

Comment: я писал по поводу .htaccess - там ничего нет. Сделал поиск и вот что нашел

Comment: `public function testHandleExceptionWithARedirectionResponse(){
        $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
        $dispatcher->addListener(KernelEvents::EXCEPTION, function ($event) {
            $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse('/login', 301));
        });
        $kernel = new HttpKernel($dispatcher, $this->getResolver(function () { throw new AccessDeniedHttpException(); }));
        $response = $kernel->handle(new Request());
        $this->assertEquals('301', $response->getStatusCode());
        $this->assertEquals('/login', $response->headers->get('Location'));
    }`

Comment: только я не понимаю что это((

Comment: и я понял, что за показ страниц отвечает роутинг, но для главной есть такое `fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"`, если его убрать - перестает сайт работать